# Responsive Background Images - Media Queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, background-image

I've been searching and haven't found anything that solves my question. So basically i'm looking for a way to use 3 different images in a div using media queries.

Simply this:

1. Wider rectangle image for large displays
2. Shorter rectangle image for tablets
3. square image for phone

I've looked into the background-image idea and the closest ive been able to get is using an invisible png to hold the "ratio". But all of the images i want to use will have different ratios.

Any ideas?

Comment: how about using bootstrap?
here's a link for you to check. =)
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_images.asp

Comment: I'm using skeleton css. I'm quite comfortable with html/css but i never tried to do this exact thing before using images. I figured it would be as easy as using media queries for font styles, etc... Seems like its not.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but this is probably what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: When i hit a media query breakpoint, i want to have a different image be used in that div... much like how its done with font size, etc.

Comment: What is the problem with overriding the background-image property in a media query ? This should work. Though if you want to use actual <img> tags, you should look for html5's "srcset" and "sizes" attributes